# Android - How identify if an app was installed in root mode?

Tags: android, root

I can get a list of applications (PackageInfo/ApplicationInfo) installed on device, but would like to know if each app was installed by default or by telephone company (In Brazil the company install some apps that we can't remove without root permission).
I was thinking in identify if the application is in root mode, but I don't know how to do that. Somebody would help me?

---

I want something like that:

```
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
List<PackageInfo> packagesInfo = pm.getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
for (PackageInfo packageInfo : packagesInfo) {
    if (isPackageRooted(packageInfo) { // this method I need!!!!!
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: What **exactly** do you mean by "root mode"?   There is no such concept in Android with respect to applications.  Do you mean preintalled apps located on the /system partition rather than on /data ?

Comment: Chris Stratton, I need to know wich application come by default in device. Because this applications i can't uninstall.

Answer (score 0):

If you want list of apps install on phone do following

You could probably do worse than to look into the Android source code.
You can browse it online, starting here:

[android.git.kernel.org Git](http://android.googlesource.com/)

Although if you want to be able to search and check for cross-references you might want to download all the code, and look at in Eclipse.

Here's a link to the ManageApplications class in the Settings app.
It should be a good place to start as it has to list all the applications.
There's a method called getInstalledApps() that you might want to look at.

android.git.kernel.org Git - [platform/packages/apps/Settings.git/blob - src/com/android/settings/ManageApplications.java](http://android.googlesource.com/?p=platform/packages/apps/Settings.git;a=blob;f=src/com/android/settings/ManageApplications.java;h=dfff8c92fdb738c6d84a387d24d40d98706b867d;hb=HEAD)

In above class you get thing to distinguish between root app and user app.

And If you want to Remove Default Applications from Rooted Android Phones Link is [here..](http://androidadvices.com/remove-default-applications-rooted-android-phones/)

hope this helps you..

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i just wanna identify wich application is root and wich is not, programmatically. I edit the question with more information that i need.

Comment: @BrunoNardini No applications are root

Comment: have you read ManageApplications.java, if you get list of apps then there is room for identifying which one is defualt..